# Change position of page numbers in bibliography entry and remove brackets

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to change the position of the page numbers in incollection bibliography entries and remove the brackets around them. Also, the order of editor and booktitle has to be changed. It has to look roughly like this (just the order, I do not think they care too much about commas or dots - if that's too complicated to change)

PAIL, R. (2017). Globale Schwerefeldmodellierung am Beispiel von GOCE. In Erdmessung und Satellitengeodäsie, R. RUMMEL & W. FREEDEN
(Hrsg.). Berlin: Springer Spektrum, 217–257

instead of

[image]

It is my first time working with latex ,the code looks like this

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-ibid,bibstyle = apa, apamaxprtauth=999, 
uniquelist=false, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Quellen.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {et\,al\adddot}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\space}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace} 
{\addcomma\addspace}}

\begin{document}
\parencite[220]{Pail.2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and

```
@incollection{Pail.2017,
 author = {Pail, Roland},
 title = {Globale Schwerefeldmodellierung am Beispiel von GOCE},
 pages = {217--257},
 publisher = {{Springer Spektrum}},
 editor = {Rummel, Reinhard and Freeden, Willi},
 booktitle = {Erdmessung und Satellitengeod{\"a}sie},
 year = {2017},
 address = {Berlin}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get much closer to what you want by using the standard bibliography style instead of `biblatex-apa`.

A few of the desired modifications are easier with [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext), so I'm using its `ext-authoryear-ibid` style now instead of `authoryear-ibid`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-ibid, giveninits=true, uniquelist=false, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {et\,al\adddot}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditorx}{%
  \ifnameundef{editora}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditora]{editora}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editora}{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorb}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditorb]{editorb}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorb}{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorc}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditorc]{editorc}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorc}{editor}%
     \newunit}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator}{%
  \printtext[translatortype]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumgreater{\value{translator}}{1}}
      or
      test {\ifandothers{translator}}
    }
      {\bibstring{translators}}
      {\bibstring{translator}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printnames{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{withothers}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
  \printtext[by#2type]{%
    \iffieldundef{#1type}
      {\ifboolexpr{
         test {\ifnumgreater{\value{#1}}{1}}
         or
         test {\ifandothers{#1}}
       }
         {\bibstring{#2}}
         {\bibstring{#2}}}
      {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{#1}}{1}}
            or
            test {\ifandothers{#1}}
          }
            {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}s}}
            {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}}
         {\thefield{#1type}}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addcolon\addspace} 
    {\addcomma\addspace}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Pail.2017,
  author    = {Pail, Roland},
  title     = {Globale Schwerefeldmodellierung am Beispiel von GOCE},
  pages     = {217--257},
  publisher = {Springer Spektrum},
  editor    = {Rummel, Reinhard and Freeden, Willi},
  booktitle = {Erdmessung und Satellitengeodäsie},
  year      = {2017},
  address   = {Berlin}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite[220]{Pail.2017} and \cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had found out that the APA style fits most of the requirements. I need the authors to be shown as: Roland, P., Example, A., Example, B., ...

And how can I remove the quotation marks? And "(Hrsg.)" instead of "Hrsg. von"?

Comment: @Vivi I have edited the answer to achieve the desired name format (I have not updated the picture, though). It is rarely a good idea to base a custom style on `biblatex-apa` - it can be very hard to modify it since it implements the APA style so thoroughly. Using a standard style like `authoryear` is much easier.

Comment: Great! And how can I remove the quotation marks? And put "(Hrsg.)" at the end of the editor instead of "Hrsg. von"?

Comment: @Vivi `\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}` the "Hrsg." is a bit more tricky. Give me a few minutes...

Comment: Thank you very much! I also need volume and issue as "xyz, 14(2): 1-5" instead of "xyz 14.2: 1-5" I do hope that's about it, then

Comment: One more question: URLs are shown as "URL: http...". How can I remove "URL: "? I could not find anything that worked for me.